# Get total time different between multiple time ranges

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table containing an id, an action, and a datetime field. That looks like this:

| ID | ACTION | DATETIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | start | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | end | 2022-01-01 00:04:30 |
| 1 | start | 2022-01-01 00:08:00 |
| 1 | end | 2022-01-01 00:08:30 |
| 2 | start | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | end | 2022-01-01 00:01:30 |
| 2 | start | 2022-01-01 00:02:00 |
| 2 | end | 2022-01-01 00:02:45 |

I am trying to figure out a way to add up all of the times between each start/end pair. This is something I could figure out in Python or JS, but I'm having trouble figuring out the logic in SQL since there can be more than one start/end instance per ID.

Anyone know of a way to iterate through each ID group, ordered by datetime, and get the total time between each range using `DATEDIFF`? For the table above, the end result should look like this:

| ID | TOTAL_TIME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:05:00 |
| 2 | 00:02:15 |

Trying to avoid using UDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem which we can solve using the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATETIME) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ACTION ORDER BY DATETIME) rn2
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT ID,
           DATEDIFF(minute,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'start' THEN DATETIME END),
                    MAX(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'end'   THEN DATETIME END)) AS diff
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY id, rn1 - rn2
)

SELECT ID, SUM(diff) AS TOTAL_TIME_IN_MINUTES
FROM cte2
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to be exactly what I needed. I've never heard of gaps and islands before so this has given me something new to learn about.